# unwind in current context instead of full screen

Tags: ios, containers, segue

My question is about a very particular situation.
My english is not very impressive so let's take a look at the storyboard first :

... Gasp !!! I can't post images !!!

Well... It won't be easy but let's go...

We have :

- First a tabBarController with 2 ViewControllers.

  - The second one will be called "Vue 2.1". It is a subclass of UIViewController with a wonderful UITableView and a navigationBar within. The navigationBar has a button "Add" with a triggered segue to a new navigation controller. The segue is Present Modally in full screen.

    - The navigation controller lead to another UIViewController called "Vue 2.2" with a Container.

      - The container embed another navigation controller and a UITableViewController called "Vue 2.3".

        - A last "Add" button in the "Vue 2.3" has a triggered segue to a new navigation controller and a last UIViewController ("Vue 2.4"). This last segue is present modally in current context.

In Vue 2.2 and 2.4, there are buttons in the navigation bar connected with unwind functions of vue 2.1 and 2.3 (retour21 and retour23)

I made the example with less detail as possible. There are only two class for the views "Vue 2.1" and "Vue 2.3".

Here the 2 classes :

Vue 2.1 :

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

    @IBAction func retour21(segue :UIStoryboardSegue) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        var cell = self.table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel.text = ""
        return cell
    }   
}
```

Vue 2.3 :

```
class vue23ViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBAction func retour23(segue :UIStoryboardSegue) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Impressive, uh ?

So, what's the problem ?

Run the application. The tabBar work correctly. The second view appears. The click on the add button opens the Vue 2.2 without problem in full screen. The Vue 2.2 contains the Vue 2.3 with his own add button. Click on it : the "Vue 2.4" appear in the container : good ! But when you click on the button to unwind to the "Vue 2.3", this one appears in the full screen and not in the container of the "Vue 2.2"...

Why ?

I am looking for an answer since few days... Please help me !!!

And if i insert another container but in the "Vue 2.1". If this container embed the navigation controller of the "Vue 2.3", everything works well !

I am lost...

Comment: I have found another solution :

Comment: I insert a navigation controller between the TabBarController and i change the first add's segue to be a show (e. g. push) segue. It works !
But why the navigation controller is not enough ? Mystery !